# horizontal CSS transition with fixed elements?

Tags: css, transition, fixed

I'm working on a multidevice web page, i want to make a CSS transition of a div (.carrousel) witch contains 3 other div (.bloc1 to 3) positionned horizontally using float left
First, only div 2 and 3 are shown (negatif left on .carrousel and overflow hidden on the container .global)
A clic on the link 'Show blocs {1, 2}' moves the .carousel to right and shows these blocs
To ensure the transition happens smoothly i've adopted the HTML structure below.
The problem is that the fixed elements are'nt positionned correctly in Chrome, IE8, Android 4.03 et 3.02
But under Firefox 15.0, IE9 and also IE7! things are working well...
Any suggestion on changing the HTML structure is welcome as the transition effect remain untouched... But i don't want to use some hacks or specific CSS by device

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2" />
    <style type="text/css">

        * { margin:0; padding:0; }
        a img { border:none; }
        body { font-family:Tahoma; font-size:12px; }
        p { margin:10px 0; }

        .global { width:940px; overflow:hidden; position:relative; margin:20px auto; border:#F00 solid 1px; }

        .carrousel { width:1660px; overflow:hidden; position:relative; top:0;
            -webkit-transition: left .2s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: left .2s ease-in-out;
            -ms-transition: left .2s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: left .2s ease-in-out;
            transition: left .2s ease-in-out; }

        .bloc { float:left; padding:5px; margin:5px; text-aligh:center; }               

        .bloc1 { width:700px; height:400px; background-color:#F00; }

        .bloc2 { width:200px; height:300px; background-color:#999; }
        .nav { position:fixed; z-index:2; background-color:#F90; width:200px; }
        .nav a { display:block; margin:10px 0; }


        .bloc3 { width:700px; min-height:300px; position:relative; background-color:#FF0; }
        .header { width:700px; height:50px; position:fixed; z-index:2; background-color:#6FF; }
        .list { height:3000px; padding-top:50px; position:relative; z-index:1; background-color:#9C3; }

        .carrousel.showblocs23 { left:-720px; }

        .carrousel.showblocs12 { left:0; }
        .carrousel.showblocs12 .header { position:relative; }           

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

    <title>blocr</title>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="global">

        <div class="carrousel showblocs23">  

            <div class="bloc bloc1">
            bloc 1              
            </div>

            <div class="bloc bloc2">
            bloc 2
                <div class="nav">
                fixed nav<br />
                    <a href="#" onclick="$('.carrousel').removeClass('showblocs23').addClass('showblocs12'); return false;">
                    Show blocs {1, 2}
                    </a>                                
                    <a href="#" onclick="$('.carrousel').removeClass('showblocs12').addClass('showblocs23'); return false;">
                    Show blocs {2, 3}
                    </a>
                </div>                
            </div>

            <div class="bloc bloc3">

            bloc 3

                <div class="header">
                    bloc 3 header fixed
                </div>

                <div class="list">
                    bloc 3 long list
                </div>

            </div>

        </div><!-- /carrousel --> 

    </div><!-- /global -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. i agree, but when "left" and "top" properties are not specified, a fixed element is first positionned relative to the parent element... and then it does'nt scroll with the window... now i've discovered that this first positioning depends on the browser interpretation...
2. i'm using "z-index" property to place my fixed elements in the top of the layers when they are superposed...

Comment: i found the solution for this problem, i simply used "margin-left" instead of "left" property to place the .carousel, so just update the css classes .carrousel, .carrousel.showblocs23 and .carrousel.showblocs12 using "margin-left" instead.

Answer (score 2):

There are two main issues here, unless I misunderstand your intent.

1. It seems that you've mixed `absolute` and `fixed` positioning. The `position: fixed` property causes an element to be positioned relative to the **browser window**, not its parent div. You are looking for `position: absolute` for the `.header` and `.list` classes.
2. You are using `z-index` in places where it is not necessary. You can remove the `z-index` property from all of your classes. This reveals another issue, your `.list` class needs to have `margin-top: 50px` instead of `padding-top: 50px`. Padding fills in the area within the border of an element, while margin creates an invisible margin outside the border of an element. For more on [margin](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp) and [padding](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp), look to the w3 schools for more information.

Here is the JSFiddle for the working code: http://jsfiddle.net/sjAcV/

Here is the JSFiddle for your original code: http://jsfiddle.net/VVZrg/

Comment: Also, this seems to be your first post, welcome to Stack Overflow. In the future, if you want your question to have more views and hopefully good answers, try setting more general tags. The tags you set are very specific. HTML and CSS are two tags that should absolutely be applied to this question.